# converting the below data structure of Map into another data structure in java

Tags: java

I am basically trying to create the following data structure:

```
  Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>
```

I want something like this shown below:

```
Key         Value

B1          payerName  ----> "wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"
            fixedRate ----->"dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"

B2          payerName  ----> "SSSwpn", "wpfSSSnb", "GGGdgeft", "xbtYYYYhy"
            fixedRate ----->"WWdd", "wTTYw", "YYYYtrrty", "IIIhttyure"
```

so what basically I have tried is but please advise me is there any other way or data structure in which i can achieve the same below functionality through linked list or tree please advise

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> ultimateMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String, List<String>>> ();

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map1.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
    map1.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map2.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("SSSwpn", "wpfSSSnb", "GGGdgeft", "xbtYYYYhy"));
    map2.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("WWdd", "wTTYw", "YYYYtrrty", "IIIhttyure"));

    ultimateMap.put("B1", map1);
    ultimateMap.put("B2", map2);
```

advise me is there any other way or data structure in which i can achieve the same below functionality through linked list or tree please advise

Comment: I don't think your implementation is bad...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This feels a bit too much like example code for me to recommend it to be posted on CR.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> ultimateMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String, List<String>>> ();
```

Is a good way of implementing your ultimate map. I don't think there can be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two data structures based on your question.Hope this helps your idea

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestClass().LoadData();
}

private void LoadData() {

    //1 Assuming payerName List and fixedRate list are of different sizes
    Map<String, PayerDataModel1> detailMap = new HashMap<>();
    PayerDataModel1 p1 = new PayerDataModel1();
    p1.payerName.add("p1");
    p1.fixedRate.add("f1");
    p1.payerName.add("p2");
    p1.fixedRate.add("f2");
    p1.payerName.add("p3");
    p1.fixedRate.add("f3");
    p1.payerName.add("p4");
    p1.fixedRate.add("f4");

    detailMap.put("B1", p1);

    p1 = new PayerDataModel1();
    p1.payerName.add("pp1");
    p1.fixedRate.add("ff1");
    p1.payerName.add("pp2");
    p1.fixedRate.add("ff2");
    p1.payerName.add("pp3");
    p1.fixedRate.add("ff3");
    p1.payerName.add("pp4");
    p1.fixedRate.add("ff4");

    detailMap.put("B2", p1);

    System.out.println(detailMap.get("B1").fixedRate.get(0));
    System.out.println(detailMap.get("B1").payerName.get(0));

    System.out.println(detailMap);
    //2 Assuming each payerName has a fixedRate [so list are of same sizes]
    Map<String, PayerDataModel2> detailMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    PayerDataModel2 payerdata = new PayerDataModel2();
    payerdata.addNew("p1", "f1");
    payerdata.addNew("p2", "f2");
    payerdata.addNew("p3", "f3");

    detailMap2.put("B1", payerdata);

    payerdata = new PayerDataModel2();
    payerdata.addNew("pp1", "ff1");
    payerdata.addNew("pp2", "ff2");
    payerdata.addNew("pp3", "ff3");
    detailMap2.put("B2", payerdata);

    System.out.println(detailMap2.get("B1").payerDataList.get(0).payerName);

    System.out.println(detailMap2);
}
}

class PayerDataModel1 {

ArrayList<String> payerName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> fixedRate = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "payerName - " + payerName + " fixedRate - " + fixedRate;
}
 }

 class PayerDataModel2 {

ArrayList<PayerDataModelDetail> payerDataList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addNew(String payerName, String fixedRate) {
    PayerDataModelDetail p = new PayerDataModelDetail();
    p.fixedRate = fixedRate;
    p.payerName = payerName;
    payerDataList.add(p);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return payerDataList.toString();
}
 }

class PayerDataModelDetail {

String payerName;
String fixedRate;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "payerName - " + payerName + " fixedRate - " + fixedRate;
}

}
```

Output for first model

```
{B2=payerName - [pp1, pp2, pp3, pp4] fixedRate - [ff1, ff2, ff3, ff4], B1=payerName - [p1, p2, p3, p4] fixedRate - [f1, f2, f3, f4]}
```

Output for second model

```
{B2=[payerName - pp1 fixedRate - ff1, payerName - pp2 fixedRate - ff2, payerName - pp3 fixedRate - ff3], B1=[payerName - p1 fixedRate - f1, payerName - p2 fixedRate - f2, payerName - p3 fixedRate - f3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only need a single map that maps from a `String` to a `List<String>`. If you wan't to associate a name with each map, just encapsulate them in a wrapper class.

I would create a `CustomMap` class that contains a `String mapName` and `Map<String, List<String>> payerAndRateMap`:

```
class CustomMap
{
    private String mapName;
    private Map<String, List<String>> payerAndRateMap;

    CustomMap(String mapName, Map<String, List<String>> payerAndRateMap)
    {
        this.mapName = mapName;
        this.payerAndRateMap = payerAndRateMap;  
    }

    public String getMapName()
    {
        return mapName;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getPayerAndRateMap()
    {
        return payerAndRateMap;
    }
}
```

I'd then create instances of this `CustomMap` in the following manner:

```
Map<String, List<String>> payerAndRateMap = new HashMap<>();
payerAndRateMap.put("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
payerAndRateMap.put("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"));

CustomMap customMap1 = new CustomMap("B1", payerAndRateMap);
```

This way your client code **reads better**, for instance:

```
customMap1.getPayerAndRateMap().get("payerName");
```

is more lucid to the reader than saying:

```
ultimateMap.get("B1").get("xyz");
```

Comment: can you please correct the above pojo named CustomMap  i am using jdk 1.5 , rest your approach is very cool

Comment: payerAndRateMap.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
  payerAndRateMap.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"));

Comment: i am getting complier error for above put lines please advise how to avoid this compilation error in put lines

Comment: @sdsdfdfdg, Could you tell me what **exactly** the compiler is saying? It looks good to me, refer [this](http://ideone.com/rFh1e5) code sample.

Comment: Well it was some thing related to put method signature mismatch as the put method is using array list inside it

Comment: How did you declare your map? If you say `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`, there shouldn't be any signature mismatch for the `put()` method.

Comment: Also, do you have all the necessary imports? `import java.util.*;`

Comment: Yes can you please advice any other custom data structure to obtain the same mite bhi linked list or tree

Comment: I am very much excited to use custom data structure plrase

Comment: In this case, I don't see a need for linked lists or trees. Also, if you were satisfied with my answer, please accept the answer and give it an upvote but only do it if you're satisfied.